# How to get GRAPH API token in office.js to use in Online/desktop outlook?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am developing add-in based on `office.js` for Outlook and desktop one. In addin I want option to saved previusly emails(their id ) open them in new window by click. For that I need to make identifiers immutable. To make identifiers immutable I need to use GRAPH API.
More preferably  this [POST method to transform dynamic IDs to constant ones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-translateexchangeids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/translateExchangeIds
```

But here is a problem to use this method I need authorization token to be passed in headers of that request.
**Question is how to get needed GRAPH API authorization token using office.js functional?**

### What tokens I tried:

- Using `Office.auth.getAccessToken()` but as result of request I got error in my online outlook -  `API is not supported in this platform`.
- Using `Office.auth.getAccessToken()` but I got same result -  `API is not supported in this platform`
- Using `Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync()` yeah I got as resultat token, but if you pass this token in GRAPHS API request headers then it throws error in console what request was bad (bad Authorization token)

Comment: To be able to use the Microsoft Graph API, you need to setup your add-in to use Single Sign-On (SSO). The instructions are here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/use-sso-to-get-office-signed-in-user-token?tabs=vs2019.Did you go through these instructions before calling `Office.auth.getAccessToken()` ? Also, what is the error code that you are getting? For example, are you getting error code 13000? The token from `Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync()` cannot be used with the Microsoft Graph.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT the error code  on Office.auth.getAccessToken() is `13012` here is a link with method to call this func and the result of call https://i.imgur.com/gYj6csx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand how the `Single Sign-On (SSO)` works in Office add-ins I'd suggest creating a new sample add-in and run the code under the debugger. The process is documented in the [Single sign-on (SSO) quick start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/sso-quickstart) guide. Also you may find the [sample add-in which uses SSO](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/auth/Office-Add-in-NodeJS-SSO) helpful.

The `getAccessToken` method calls the Azure Active Directory V 2.0 endpoint to get an access token to your add-in's web application. Enables add-ins to identify users. Server-side code can use this token to access Microsoft Graph for the add-in's web application by using the ["on behalf of" OAuth flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of). This API requires a single sign-on configuration that bridges the add-in to an Azure application. Office users sign-in with Organizational Accounts and Microsoft Accounts. Microsoft Azure returns tokens intended for both user account types to access resources in the Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Can you please provide the specific Azure Active Directory V 2.0 endpoint to get an access token , I tried to get token using client credential but not able to get the  "on behalf of" token on the server side, this is the end poitn that I tried to get token with "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenent Id}/oauth2/v2.0/token", By proving the client id, seceret scope, grant type 
grant_type=client_credentials&
client_id=xxxx&
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&
client_secret=xxxxx&
requested_token_use=on_behalf_of
can you help me out with this.